# How can $f(x)$ be constant in integration?

Tags: calculus

I know that separable differential equations are like this $y'=g(y)h(x)$. How can we accept that $h(x)$ can be a constant and proceed as if it was a function of $x$?

Answer (score 5):

By writing $h(x)$, we mean that $h$ *may* depend on $x$, but **not** on y; it doesn't 'have' to depend on $x$ - i.e. it may be a constant - that's a function too!

In that case, you could consider yourself lucky since a constant function is an easy function :-), which makes it easy to integrate as well.

Comment: well that's very tricky because I thought we use constants to describe a constant and we use a function to describe a function!!!!

Comment: Isn't $h(x)=4$ a **constant function**?

Comment: ergon: you should look up what a function really is, or how it is defined in your (math) notes. You'll see that it doesn't exclude "constant functions". Loosely speaking, a (real) function assigns a real number $f(x)$ to every $x$. A very "boring", but not "illegal" way, would be to assign **the same** number to every $x$, say the number $c$. Then $f(x) = c$ is a constant function.